# Modfiying Android Manifest

Tags: android

So I have been following a tutorial titled 31 days of Android. I am having an issue with one of the tutorials. It calls for me to modify the androidmanifest.xml file but when I do but it doesn't work. Everytime I run the application it crushes after I press button 2. Here is the code they wanted me to add

```
<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:name="MyApplication">
```

and here is the code looks after I have added that code to my file.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MyApplication">
```

I did not add the android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" because it gave me an error which read "no resoucre found that matches the given name". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your app crashes, include in your post the stack trace from LogCat. Also include the relevant code. You have no relevant information here.

Comment: Nor do you. I'm in the process of learning android, so do not know how to get the stack trace. I check the debug panel but it failed to show anything.

Comment: Actually I did provide some information that should get you started: LogCat. Select the DDMS perspective in Eclipse and then the LogCat tab. You can filter by the error level.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because there is no icon in your project, 
Look in Project/res/drawable/ ... 
The ic_launcher is the default icon, so just replace

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

By :

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```